# Динамическая запись данных из таблицы postgres

Tags: postgresql, golang

Всем привет
Использую pgx.
Вот код получения данных из таблицы в которой два столбца

```
func GetAll(aim, table string) (string, string) {
    dbitem, _ := pgx.Connect(context.Background(), dbconn)
    defer dbitem.Close(context.Background())
    name, data := "", "" //вот здесь создать один интерфейс(например) 
    err := dbitem.QueryRow(context.Background(), "select "+aim+" from "+table).Scan(&name, &data) //здесь в интерфейс записать то, что пришло из базы.
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return name, data
}

func main() {
    log.Println(GetAll("*", "textData"))
}
```

.Scan требует от меня 2 переменные, чтоб положить в них значения двух столбцов, что логично.

Но я бы хотел, не быть првязанным к количеству переменных и с помощью Scan записывать все что приходит  из таблицы, допустим, в интерфейс. Чтобы не создавать переменные, не ограничиваться количеством переменных и т.д.

Как я могу это сделать?
Если я использую один интерфейс, то Scan ругается что ему все равно нужен второй field. Как провернуть то что мне нужно?

Answer (score 0):

Поковырялся немного и, кажется, решил проблему. ЧАстично пока что, буду дальше ковырять)

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/jackc/pgx/v4"
)

var dbconn = "postgres://user:pass@localhost:5432/test"

func Get(aim, table string) []string {
    dbitem, _ := pgx.Connect(context.Background(), dbconn)
    defer dbitem.Close(context.Background())
    data, _ := dbitem.Query(context.Background(), "select "+aim+" from "+table)
    var dataSlc []string
    for data.Next() {
        a, _ := data.Values()
        for _, it := range a {
            dataSlc = append(dataSlc, fmt.Sprint(it))
        }
    }
    return dataSlc
}

func main() {
    Data := Get("*", "textData")
    for num, it := range Data {
        log.Println(it, num)
    }
}
```

Только не получается вернуть элементы массива(((Мне нужно их использовать в других функциях(

Comment: что значит не получается вернуть элементы массива? вы же делаете return dataSlc

Comment: @SeniorPomidor я возвращаю массив и потом в другой функции получаю его элементы. А хотелось возвращать элементы сразу из Get. Но после первого return функция завершается(что логично)и возвращается только первый элемент. Но я думаю по другому никак наверно) а есть ли другой способ брать значения из бд ? Или это нормальный вариант? Я просто не видел как в проде делают) в частности мне ещё не нравится как я конвертирую в string.(Sprint). Тоже думаю, можно лучше сделать)

Comment: а в базе сколько элементов?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor Подразумевается, что неизвестно))Но я переделал уже все.. Сделал, чтобы можно было аргуменом полное sql выражение вбивать [здесь](https://github.com/udonetsm/dbservice) можно посмотреть

Comment: Перейдите на использование gorm.io, к примеру, чтобы не было нужды использовать неопределенные типы. Обозначьте структуру таблицы через привязку к struct и извлекайте нужные вам данные. И гадать не придется, и меньше путаницы и возможностей налететь на баги.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov посмотрю, спасибо за наводку) но предварительно, виду проблему того что будет много описательно части структур. Ибо сервис подразумевает работу с несколькими таблицами) по каждой придется делать структуру?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov но с другой стороны, можно сразу упаковывать json и делать rest...хм ...нужно посмотреть)

Comment: @umd под каждую нужно делать структуру, эта основа ORM, хотя можно и чистые запросы делать и структуры для ответов создавать - вариантов много.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Если не затруднит, [посмотрите](https://go.dev/play/p/6MvaFiox6pM) пожалуйста, правильно ли я понял?Про структуры...

Comment: @DanielProtopopov
даже [так](https://go.dev/play/p/t7izA9zAWh-) все таки

Comment: вам нужна только одна структура type XXX struct для описания таблицы, смотрите документацию [gorm.io](https://gorm.io/ru_RU/docs/index.html). Нет смысла создавать структуру для записи, а другую для чтения.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov что-то никак не пойму, как мне делать десериализацию не используя вторe. структуру. Она же мне нужна для того чтобы туда записать то, что получится после json.unmarshal. Понятно, что если нужно что-то в базу записать, то можно эту же структуру использовать, а вот как одну структуру использовать для получения из базы и десериализации, не создавая при этом ворох переменных, я понять не могу) задача стоит, достать из базы произвольное количество данных и прочитать то, что прочитается)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov кароч, неизвестно, кто, как и сколько даных досьтанет из базы, просто нужно указать каккие поля при этом брать(слайс string в main)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov получилось все) вопрос снимаю)